# Rotate and balance

Tags: wheel-balance

Recently bought a car a few months ago and got the carfax update the other day apparently the previous owner never rotated the tires so I proceeded to do so yesterday. While getting the rotation the tech never checked if the wheels were balanced should I be concerned or is this normal that when rotating tires wheels you do not necessarily have to get balanced?

Comment: Unless you see obvious signs of uneven wear, or noticed pulsing while driving, the tires are probably _balanced enough_. I've never seen techs balance car tires when rotating them, although I'm sure some do. This is probably because cars are stable and tough enough to tolerate a greater imbalance than normal even wear would provide.

Comment: @the_storyteller - If you pay for a rotation *and balance*, they should be getting what they are paying for ... however, if the OP only asked for a tire rotation, all bets are off.